# firestore data becomes null outside of then()

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
  String? username;
  Future<String?> get getUserName async {
    final docRef =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("test").doc("$getEmail");
    docRef.get().then(
      (DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
        username = data["property"];
        print(username); // it's not null I can read data from here accurately.
      },
      onError: (e) => print("Error getting document: $e"),
    );
    print(username); // it's null
    return username; // it returns null.
  }
```

I can read data correctly inside of then() but when I assign data to varriable declared outside of method, it becomes null.Hence, I can't return my future string to future builder.

Answer (score 1):

Data is loaded from Firestore (and from most cloud APIs) asynchronously. It's easiest to see what this means by adding some more print statements:

```
print("Before calling get()");
final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("test").doc("$getEmail");
docRef.get().then(
  print("Got data");
});
print("After calling get()");
```

Now if you run the above code, it prints:

> Before calling get()
>
> After calling get()
>
> Got data

Now this is probably not the order you expected the output in, but it is completely as expected and does explain why you're not seeing the user name printed: by the time that print statement runs, the data hasn't been loaded yet.

---

If you want to use `then()` the solution is always the same: any code that needs the data has to be in the `then` callback, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized.

An alternative though is to use `await` when calling `get()` instead of using `then()`:

```
final docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("test").doc("$getEmail");
DocumentSnapshot doc = await docRef.get().

final data = doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
username = data["property"];

return username;
```

---

Since dealing with asynchronous APIs is very common in modern programming, I recommend checking out:

- The codelab [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)