# Flutter firestore access value from .get().then function outside of the .then

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this set of code:

```
      String weightValue = "start";
      //todo: get current weight format from user settings
      db.collection('UserSettings').doc(userID).get().then((value) {
        weightValue = value['weightFormat'];
      });
      print(weightValue);
```

I can print the weightValue insite the .then() but I can not access the weightValue outside of the .then()

I have tried to not use a .then() and use the await but I am in a streamBUilder:

```
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      String weightValue = await getWeightSettings(userID, db);
```

and if I await that fucntion I created to get the value, I have to make the builder async:

```
 (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) async {
```

and then I get this error:

> The argument type 'Future Function(BuildContext,
> AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>)' can't be assigned to the
> parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext,
> AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>)'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the value of this variable outside the .then((){}); statement in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53916529/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-this-variable-outside-the-then-statement-in-fl) and also [firestore data becomes null outside of then()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72391495/13130697)

Comment: @Dharmaraj so that say to use an await, and async but that did not work for me becasue I am in a stram builder. 

Will update my code above to show more details as to why

Comment: @Dharmaraj more details added to my question above on why the await doesnt work for me.

Comment: Note that the answer says "*If you use the .then() clause you need to do all your work inside it and **you can't use its values outside** because you don't know when you are receiving the answer.*".  So if you are not using await as an alternative, it is just not going to work the way you want.

Comment: Can I return widgets from inside the then to the stream builder....

Comment: If you want to use an additional asynchronous value in the `builder` of your `StreamBuilder`, you should return a `FutureBuilder` to encapsulate that additional asynchronous behavior.